# Why Windows Service support to add controls (components) like a GUI application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

As I know, Windows Service is No-GUI application. We will control it using Services tool in Administrator Tools.

However, why I create a Windows Service project (C#) from Visual Studio template. I read code Service1.cs, I see a method InitializeComponent() similar with Windows Form application. When I double click on Service1.cs to open in designer mode, I can drag or drop to add or remove controls (components) in this service. I don't know the purpose of this feature.

Please help me when to use this feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really a designer, it is merely a visual representation of the components of the service. You cannot design anything, just select the components like the BackgroundWorker, Timer, Service Controller, etc.

It is just a convenient way to manage properties and events of some components.

Answer (score 2):

Components are different from controls.  They are non-visual objects that allow you to package functionality in a way that can be included in the toolbox and configured in the designer like a control, but work better with services and other non-gui apps.

Comment: I can't imagine your idea. I think we should have samples. Thanks.

Comment: @lu where did you look for samples?